# Filter based on the presence of a property (regardless of its value)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm new to SQLAlchemy, and am doing the following query:

```
ratings = meta.Session.query(Thing) \
    .filter_by(owner = user.id)\
    .filter_by(objType = 'rating')\
    .filter(Thing.data.any(with_characteristic('ratingType', 'binary')))\
  # .filter(Thing.data.any(with_characteristic('fooCode', '.*')))\
  # .filter(Thing.data.any(with_characteristic_like('fooCode', '.*')))\
    .order_by('-lastUpdated').all()
```

As is, this gives me all the Things owned by `user` with an objType of rating and ratingType of binary. What I'm trying to do in the two commented lines is filter that to binary ratings whose data objects contain a `fooCode` property. I don't care what the fooCode is, I just want to filter my results to things that have one - hence my attempt to use a regex there - which isn't working (I'm getting empty result sets).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using vertical mapping like the one shown in the [example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/_modules/examples/vertical/dictlike.html), just add another helper method and use it:

```
class Thing(...):
    # ...
    @classmethod
    def with_characteristic(self, key, value):
        return self.facts.any(key=key, value=value)

    @classmethod
    def has_characteristic(self, key):
        return self.facts.any(key=key)
```

and use it:

```
ratings = (meta.Session.query(Thing)
    .filter_by(owner = user.id)
    .filter_by(objType = 'rating')
    .filter(Thing.data.any(with_characteristic('ratingType', 'binary')))
    .filter(Thing.data.any(has_characteristic('fooCode')))
    .order_by('-lastUpdated').all()
)
```